# Как сделать так, чтобы не обрезало картинку с абсолютным позиционированием на стыке двух блоков?

Tags: html, css, css3

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы изображение с ребенком не обрезал начинающийся новый блок (отмечен синим выделением инстпектора браузера).

Пробовал играться с `overflow: visible;` для родителей - не помогло, то ли неправильно делаю, то ли беда в другом.

Так же пробовал `z-index`, результат тот же.

Код прикреплен, ели Вам удобнее так - [вот ссылка на сайт](http://lebedeva.wg3036.wg01.ru)

```css
.sp-page-builder .page-content #section-id-1562845349734 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-image: url(/images/2019/07/11/babybg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
}

.sppb-row-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-id-1562844126074" class="sppb-section ">
  <div class="sppb-row-overlay"></div>
  <div class="sppb-row-container">
    <div class="sppb-section-title sppb-text-center">
      <h3 class="sppb-title-heading">А также:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sppb-row">
      <div class="sppb-col-md-2" id="column-wrap-id-1562844126075">
        <div id="column-id-1562844126075" class="sppb-column">
          <div class="sppb-column-addons">
            <div id="sppb-addon-1562845350263" class="clearfix">
              <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html ">
                <div class="sppb-addon-content"><img src="/images/microbes.png" class="microbes"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sppb-col-md-8" id="column-wrap-id-1562844126078">
        <div id="column-id-1562844126078" class="sppb-column">
          <div class="sppb-column-addons">
            <div id="sppb-addon-1562844987212" class="clearfix">
              <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html ">
                <div class="sppb-addon-content"><img src="/images/bant.png" class="bant2"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sppb-addon-1562844126077" class="clearfix">
              <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html ">
                <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                  <div class="item-overlay">
                    <div class="item-wrapper">
                      <div class="item-title">Онлайн школа:<br><span class="main-name">"Здоровье Вашего малыша - в ваших <br>руках!"</span></div>
                      <div class="item-desk">Какие разираются вопросы?</div>
                      <div class="item-desk-ul">
                        <ul class="item-list-parent">
                          <li>Вопрос 1</li>
                          <li>Вопрос 2</li>
                          <li>Вопрос 3</li>
                          <li>Вопрос 4</li>
                          <li>Вопрос 5</li>
                          <li>Вопрос 6</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <a class="get-acsess-btn">Узнать подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sppb-col-md-2" id="column-wrap-id-1562844126085">
        <div id="column-id-1562844126085" class="sppb-column">
          <div class="sppb-column-addons">
            <div id="sppb-addon-1562845349737" class="clearfix">
              <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html ">
                <div class="sppb-addon-content"><img src="/images/cleanbaby.png" class="cleanbaby"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="section-id-1562845349734" class="sppb-section ">
  <div class="sppb-row-overlay"></div>
  <div class="sppb-row-container">
    <div class="sppb-section-title sppb-text-center">
      <h3 class="sppb-title-heading">И наконец:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sppb-row">
      <div class="sppb-col-md-2" id="column-wrap-id-1562845349735">
        <div id="column-id-1562845349735" class="sppb-column">
          <div class="sppb-column-addons"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sppb-col-md-8" id="column-wrap-id-1562845349736">
        <div id="column-id-1562845349736" class="sppb-column">
          <div class="sppb-column-addons">
            <div id="sppb-addon-1562845350202" class="clearfix">
              <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html ">
                <div class="sppb-addon-content"><img src="/images/bant.png" class="bant2"> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sppb-addon-1562845349738" class="clearfix">
              <div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-raw-html ">
                <div class="sppb-addon-content">
                  <div class="item-overlay">
                    <div class="item-wrapper">
                      <div class="item-title">Онлайн-вебинар для врачей:<br><span class="main-name">"Симбиотики нормофорины в практике <br>клинициста. Опыт применения.<br>Механизмы лействия"</span></div>
                      <div class="item-desk">Вам будет интересно, если:</div>
                      <div class="item-desk-ul">
                        <ul class="item-list-parent">
                          <li>Причина 1</li>
                          <li>Причина 2</li>
                          <li>Причина 3</li>
                          <li>Причина 4</li>
                          <li>Причина 5</li>
                          <li>Причина 6</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <a class="get-acsess-btn">Узнать подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sppb-col-md-2" id="column-wrap-id-1562845349739">
        <div id="column-id-1562845349739" class="sppb-column">
          <div class="sppb-column-addons"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вроде проблемы на сайте нет

Comment: Скорее всего изображение обрезается не новым блоком, а границами блока, в котором находится. Обратите внимание на блок #column-wrap-id-1562844126085 - изображение выходит за его рамки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изображение обрезается границами секции снизу на 47 пикселей, потому что у вас:
а) стоит свойство `bottom:-47px`, из-за чего картинка сдвинута ниже границы секции
б) следующая секция находится вплотную к предыдущей и перекрывает эту картинку. Если вы отключите у следующей секции `background-image`, сами увидите.

Сейчас у вас это нивелируется тем, что секции поставлен нижний паддинг в 50 пикселей. Это вполне годное решение, но не универсальное, да и нужен ли вам тот паддинг?..

`z-index` у вас не сработал потому, что взаимное расположение элементов меняется внутри их контейнера, но если сам контейнер имеет неправильный `z-index` относительно своих соседей, вам ничто не поможет. А у вас ВСЕ секции `<section>` имеют `z-index:1`, что приводит к ожидаемому результату: кто позже, тот и сверху. Но если вы той секции, в которой находится ваша картинка, поставите хотя бы `z-index:2`, все станет как надо.